# Move multiple folders from one subversion repository to another subversion repository

Tags: repository, subversion

### Moving multiple folders from one subversion repository to another subversion repository

I've a centOS 6.4 server and with subversion 1.4.2 installed.
I've two subversion repositories in my server.

I've been using 'repoOLD' for the past two 4 months and now I've created another repo with name 'repoNEW'

'repoOLD' contains 100 folders (projects).

'repoNEW' is just created and I need to copy few projects from 'repoOLD' to 'repoNEW'

Now the problem is how can I transfer multiple folders(projects) from my 'repoOLD' to 'repoNEW'

I've tried googling but I was unable to find tutorials for moving multiple folders from one subversion repository to another repository

Comment: Do you want to retain the commit history for the folders you move? If yes, that's just the kind of thing that `git filter-branch` is good at (e.g. for trimming away the commits that don't touch the desired files) but I'm not so sure subversion can do it very well! Also NOTE: I'm going to remove the centos tag as this question really a subversion question that doesn't depend on any particular OS.

Comment: Yes I want to retain the commit history.

Answer (score 3):

Someone else may post a better answer that uses Subversion directly, but I'm going to suggest a way that involves converting to `git` and then back to Subversion, because `git`'s `filter-branch` feature is good at this.

### Clone the old svn repo to a local git repo

```
git svn clone <url-for-repoOLD>
```

I'll assume the local `git` clone is now stored in directory `repoOLD`

### In the git clone, filter out everything you don't want

Now remove everything you don't want anymore in the new repo.

```
cd repoOLD
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
    'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch dirA dirB dirC dirD' \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

...where `dirA dirB dirC dirD` are all of the directories you don't want anymore. You have to list all of the ones you want to remove.

Check this repo with `ls` and `git log` and such to make sure it contains what you want.

### Clone the new svn repo to a local git repo

```
cd ..  # (get out of repoOLD if you are still in there)
git svn clone <url-for-repoNEW>
```

I'll assume the local `git` clone is now stored in directory `repoNEW`

I will also assume that repoNEW is completely empty at this point because you haven't committed anything to it or imported anything from repoOLD.

### Import everything from the `git` clone of repoOLD

```
cd repoNEW
git remote add repoOLD ../repoOLD
git fetch repoOLD
git merge repoOLD/master
```

### Now push those changes back to the repoNEW svn server

```
git svn dcommit
```